# Equidimensionality of fibers of the map sending matrices to eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quotient-spaces

If $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ is the space of $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients in the complex numbers I can make a map:

$\phi: M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow Sym^n(\mathbb{C})$

which sends a matrix to its set of eigenvalues. I can show all fibers have the same dimension $(=n^2-n)$ by computing stabilizers of matrices in Jordan form.

Question: Is there a quicker proof or at least a reference for the fact that the fibers of this map have the same dimension?

Comment: One can use a perturbative argument to show that the map is a submersion, in which case the result is immediate (again one can take advantage of Jordan form to show this). This may or may not be faster than your Jordan canonical form approach (which should anyway be pretty efficient), depending on what facts you assume you have at hand.